# Particular solution of inhomogeneous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have $x' = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\ -1&0
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)x + \begin{pmatrix}0\\cos(2t)\end{pmatrix}$.

I find that the the solution of the homogeneous equation is $x(t) = c_1\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(t)\\-\cos(t)\end{pmatrix} + c_2 \begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)\\-\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}$.

I am wondering how to find a particular solution?

Comment: Do you have initial conditions?

Comment: Nope, I do not.

Comment: By the way, the answer is $\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-\cos(2t)\\2\sin(2t)\end{pmatrix}$ but I do not know how to get there.

Comment: That is just the particular solution, which is the integral in my solution.

Comment: The point is general solution of inhomogeneous equation = general solution of homogeneous equation + particular solution of inhomogeneous equation. I want to know how to find particular solution in this case. I don't care about the answer.

Comment: Did the answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the system:

$$X'(t) = Ax(t) + F(t), X(t_0) = C$$

the solution is given by:

$$X(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \end{bmatrix} = e^{At}~C + \int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-s)}~F(s)ds$$

**Update**

You can also re-write the system as a second order system and use Undetermined Coefficients or Variation of Parameters and others.

We have:

$$y''+y = \cos 2t$$

The homogeneous solution is:

$$y_h(t) = c_1 \cos t + c_2 \sin t$$

For the particular solution, we choose:

$$y_p(t) = a \cos 2t + b \sin 2t$$

Solving for the constants, we find $a = -\frac{1}{3}, b = 0$.

So, the particular solution is:

$$y_p(t) = -\dfrac{1}{3} \cos 2t$$

To write this as a system, we just take the derivative of this to get the other part of the solution, so we have:

$$\dfrac{2}{3} \sin 2t$$

Comment: Yeah, that formula is in my book but I think the point of the question is to find particular solution using some method like undetermined coefficient or variation of parameters...

Comment: Well, you could convert the system back into a second order system and then use undetermined coefficient or variation of parameters. Seems like a waste to write it as a system and then go backward.

Comment: @user96865: I added details as to an approach as this seems like what you were looking for. However, like I said earlier, what a waste to write it as a system if we are not going to use my first answer.

Comment: Another UV to go with green! +1